# Datatables - replacing value with icon works with one cell but not two

Tags: laravel-5, datatables

Using Laravel 5.8 and Yajra datatables I have a table and I want to replace 1 with an icon or if 0 return a blank.

In my javascript I have:

```
  "columnDefs": [{
                  "targets": 5,
                  "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                    if ( data == "1" )
                      {return '<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>';}
                    else if ( data == "0" )
                     { return ' ';}
                  },
                 }],
```

This works fine

[image]

but my problem is adding a second cell:

```
"columnDefs": [{
                  "targets": 5,
                  "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                    if ( data == "1" )
                      {return '<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>';}
                    else if ( data == "0" )
                     { return ' ';}
                  },
                  "targets": 6,
                  "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                    if ( data == "1" )
                      {return '<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>';}
                    else if ( data == "0" )
                     { return ' ';}
                  },

          }],
```

The first column (5) is back to zeros and ones but the column 6 is correct.

[image]

Help greatly appreciated indeed!

Comment: I think you might have a syntax error. You might have to wrap each `target` and `render` into an object or array of object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try multiple targets if your callback is the same:

```
"columnDefs": [{
  "targets": [5, 6],
  "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
    if ( data == "1" )
    {return '<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>';}
    else if ( data == "0" )
    { return ' ';}
  },
}],
```

Comment: Thanks - that sorted it